# Adding an image to 1 of the tabs on a TabControl, blocks my tab's text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, tabcontrol

Using Visual Studio 2005 (vb.net) (windows forms) on Windows XP, I have a standard Microsoft TabControl.

A button click adds/removes an image from 1 of the Tabs.

Seems like the image is placed OVER my tab's text, making it unreadable.
Why isn't it like it should be:  Image on the left.   Followed by text on the right.

Why is the image being placed OVER my tab's text?   Do I need to do some kind of "refresh" or "redraw" before it will appear as it should?

I don't see any way to "make the image appear on the left edge of the tab". (NOT the tab-page.) ... and then place the text just to the right of the image.  (Just like a normal image+text tab can do.)

The code is pretty simple, it just gets an image from my ImageList:

```
cfgTab.ImageKey = "PadLockClosed.png"   ' Show CLOSED PadLock
```

The tab's text changes from:

```
This is my tab text
```

to:

```
T(IMAGE HERE)is my tab text
```

The image appears *OVER* the beginning of my text.  But if I move to another tab, then move back, the image appears in the correct position:

```
(IMAGE HERE) This is my tab text
```

Comment: This is a very unusual problem to have.  At least document your Windows version, post a screenshot and post the code you use to add the image.

Comment: I have the same problem. In my scenario, I dynamically add a bunch of new tabs with images and text when the form loads - this works just fine. It is when I add a tab later that the image is on top of the text. I will update if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docking and anchoring on your Control property so it will be placed according on what you want it to display.

[Manage WinForm controls using the Anchor and Dock properties](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908)

[Resizing a Single Control In WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770094/resizing-a-single-control-in-winforms)

Regards

Comment: What would the line of code be to tell it to "anchor this tab-text to the right edge of the *TAB*. (Not the tab page.)  Actually, I would need to anchor the text "just to the right of the icon (if present)".

Comment: Have you tried the sample on the website on my post? Can you add sample photo of you form and attached it on your post. you can use http://tinypic.com/ so we can see clearly what to be solve..

Comment: I spent a lot of time reading tons of info.  None of them say ANYTHING about "here's how you dock/anchor the text that appears in the *TAB* of a TabControl".  They all give very obvious info about "how to anchor/dock buttons".  (I'm not trying to do anything with buttons)  And info about "resizing things".  (I'm not trying to resize anything.)