# How to fit Windows Form to any screen resolution in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I work on VS 2010 with C#. Even thought i set window state to maximum some panels of the form are not fit to screen when changing the resolution. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Show your work. People need more details of your problem..

Comment: What technology? WPF? Be more specific.

Comment: The title says "Windows Form", so WinForms. I'll add the tag.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't happen automatically. In order to get *child* controls to change their size with the *parent* form, you have to set some properties. Specifically, look at the [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) and [`Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) properties.

Lots of questions about this already here. I can't do better than [Simon's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/770536/366904).

Comment: Nothing related to child controls, off topic.

Comment: @David Uhh... *"some panels of the form are not fit to screen"* Panels are child controls.

Comment: the key might be on the form where some panels are hosted, if the form is not maximized, how can the "child" panels be fit to screen?

Comment: Guess we have different interpretations of the question. Sounds to me like the form *is* maximized. He set the window state to maximized. So either the UI framework is broken, or this is a common problem experienced by lots of users.

Comment: I agree with your above comment. So "some panels of the form are not fit to screen when changing the resolution" may be vague. What I guess is, the OP dynamically changes the resolution at runtime, and even though the form is set to maximized, however, the form and some controls did not change accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

As @Cody stated, Anchor and Dock can solve a lot of layout needs.  For more complicated layouts, however, you may want to look at utilizing the [TableLayoutPanel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx).